# Write a function named checkForPlagiarism that takes two arguments: an array of student answers, and snippet of text

Tags: javascript

/*Write a function named checkForPlagiarism that takes two arguments: an array of student answers, and snippet of text to check returns true if any of the essay question responses contain the text, and returns false otherwise. For each essay question in the answers array, check whether the response contains the snippet of text. If it does, return true.

Using the example answers below,

checkForPlagiarism(answers, 'spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes'); //=> true
checkForPlagiarism(answers, 'this string does not appear in the responses'); //=> false
Hint: You may want to check out the String .includes() method for this question.

Notes:

Only essay question responses count as plagiarism. If an answer to a non-essay question contains the snippet of text, that doesn't mean you should necessarily return true.
*/

In my code below I'm trying to loop through the array.response section to see if the studentAnswer string is found but it keeps returning false. I even tried an alternative and get the same conclusion.

```
 let answers = [
 {
 question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
 response: 'Metaphase',
 isCorrect: true,
 isEssayQuestion: false
 },
 {
 question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
 response: 'Esophagus',
 isCorrect: true,
 isEssayQuestion: false
 },
 {
 question: 'What are lysosomes?',
 response: 'A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal 
 cells. They are spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can 
 break down many kinds of biomolecules.',
 isCorrect: true,
 isEssayQuestion: true
 },
 {
 question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
 response: 'True',
 isCorrect: false,
 isEssayQuestion: false
 }
 ];


 function checkForPlagiarism(array, studentAnswer){
 for(let i = 0; i<array.length;i++)
 return array[i].response.includes(studentAnswer);
 }

 function checkForPlagiarism(array, studentAnswer){
 return array.includes(array => array.response === studentAnswer);
 }
```

Comment: An unconditional `return` in a loop is a bad idea: the loop will never iterate more than the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.some` method. Also, you are asked to check whether it is an essay question; otherwise it doesn't count as plagiarism:

```
function checkForPlagiarism(array, studentAnswer){
    return array.some(q => q.isEssayQuestion && q.response.includes(studentAnswer));
}
```

Comment: This one worked thank you. I trying to get better so if I'm asking a stupid question forgive me. Are you saying the .include() did not work because it did not know what to check for? Is the way I chose to approach the problem wrong?

Comment: You still need `includes` (I use it), but you applied it to the whole array object, which does not work, since `includes` does not expect a callback argument, but a plain value. `some` does what you thought `includes` would do.